# Post string value to Web Api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to post to Web Api Values controller via post:

```
// POST api/values
public void Post([FromBody]string value)
{
}
```

but the value is always null.

I'm using Postman to post this in body:  `{"test"}`  set as Json(application/json)

Comment: What you are posting is not valid JSON. What it should be is {"value":"hello world"}

Comment: what if it is a serialized json string? does it always have to be "value: ?

Comment: No you need to create a new class which contains the properties you need and then use that as the input parameter for your "Post" Method. FromBody is really only the basic way to get simple properties - Its much easier to bind a model/class.

Comment: {"value":"hello world"}  still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Sending simply "test" in quotes did the trick.